# Input text field with auto width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to set dynamically generated input text field with auto width?
I want to give text field width as auto. But now it has a minimum width. How could I override this without giving a width?

This is what I tried.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").on("click", function(evt) {
  var templ = '<input class="zt-calc-input" type="text" value="1">';
  $('button').after(templ);
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/9602/

https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/9604/

Comment: Use `max-width: something` https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/9603/

Comment: why you don't write in your class zt-calc-input that you want width: auto?

Comment: I cannot give max width since the value can differ.

Comment: I have updated the fiddle making my issue more specific.

Comment: I got the solution using js
Thanks